# CLGeocoder only working 50% of the time

Tags: ios, objective-c

so I'm trying to search a location using `CLGeocoder`,

It works the first time I do it, but it's very unreliable. Sometimes it will work, when I go back, try it again. crashes. Sometimes when I load it I get an error `PBRequester` failed with Error `Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain`, then something with the span.

This is my code:

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:placeName completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    //Error checking
    CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = [(CLCircularRegion *)placemark.region center];
    region.center.latitude = placemark.region.center.latitude;
    region.center.longitude = placemark.region.center.longitude;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    double radius = placemark.region.radius / 1000; // convert to km

    NSLog(@"Radius is %f", radius);
    span.latitudeDelta = radius / 112.0;

    region.span = span;

    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}];
```

Comment: can you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: Where is your error checking? Just putting a comment doesn't cut any ice. Why aren't you even looking to see whether you got any placemarks back?

Comment: what do you mean by entire stack trace remus?


@matt - What other errors should I be checking?

Comment: You're being passed an `error`. You're ignoring it.

Comment: but the error only occurs half the time? I've pasted the error, but I don't understand what to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During geocoding a lot of things can happen. Since it is an internet service its functionality is based on internet reachability and available band.
Fortunately  the CLGeocoder returns and error in the completion block, it is supposed that if an error happen you must handle correctly. If your app crashes is not a geocoded fault, because probably you are not handling well the error or the situation.

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:placeName completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    /* Error checking */
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"The error is %@",error.localizedDescription);
        return;
    }
    if (placemarks.count >1)
    {
        /* Handle multiple placemarks */
    }
    else {
    /* This is probably the source of your crashes if there is an error placemarks it would be an empty array, but if you ask for an object it will raise an exception for out-of-bounds index */
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0]; 
         MKCoordinateRegion region;
        region.center = [(CLCircularRegion *)placemark.region center];
        region.center.latitude = placemark.region.center.latitude;
        region.center.longitude = placemark.region.center.longitude;
        MKCoordinateSpan span;
        double radius = placemark.region.radius / 1000; /* convert to km */
        NSLog(@"Radius is %f", radius);
        span.latitudeDelta = radius / 112.0;
        region.span = span;
        [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    }
}];
```

Some suggestion:

- Handle the error
- Check how many placemarks the geocoded have be returned, they can be more than one
- In your code if the geocoded will return an empty array, asking for an object at index 0 will raise an out-of-bounds exception, always check if the count is different from 0 or use -`firstObject` method (iOS7 only)